# Replace line in file using re

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re

Why is my code not working properly?
I'm trying to replace one line in file using the `re` module:

```
import re

file = open("php.ini", "r+")

pattern = r'post_max_size = [0-9]'
result = re.search(pattern, file.read())

for line in file:        
    re.sub(pattern, "post_max_size = 1G", file.read())

file.close()
print(result)
```

I have done this by using the `fileimport` library, but this is not the way. Why can't it run properly while pattern is printing good result and `re.sub()` should replace it in this place in file?

Comment: `re.sub` creates a new string, it does not modify the file in any way.

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that after doing ...

```python
result = re.search(pattern, file.read())
```

... you are now at the end of file and so when you do ...

```python
for line in file:
```

... there are no more lines to be read. And as was commented on by @bb1, `re.sub` return a new string and does not update anything in place.

Assuming you want to replace the file with the updated text, it is far easier if you read the entire file in as one string (you are now positioned at the end of file), make the textual substitutions, re-position back to the start of the file, re-write the new string and then truncate what might be any leftover characters following in the file:

```python
import re

pattern = r'post_max_size = [0-9]'
with open("php.ini", "r+") as file:
    text = file.read()
    text = re.sub(pattern, "post_max_size = 1G", text)
    file.seek(0, 0) # seek to beginning
    file.write(text)
    file.truncate() # get rid of any trailing characters
```

But I question your `pattern` regex. What if the input had any of the following?

```
post_max_size = 1234
post_max_size=1234k
post_max_size = 1234G
```

You are only matching a *single digit*. Perhaps your pattern should be:

```python
pattern = r'post_max_size\s*=\s*[0-9]+[kKgG]?'
```

Note: There is always a bit of danger when you are updating a file in place. Should for some reason the computer crash in the middle of the write operation, you will have lost the original contents. You might want to therefore be sure to have a backup before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grouping brackets in your regular expression:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(post_max_size\s=\s[0-9])')
pattern.sub("post_max_size = 1G", file.read())
```

Comment: Creating capture group 1, which you are not even referencing in the substitution string, will not make a bit of difference. The OP has other problems and you are just creating a more expensive regex.

Answer (score 0):

Better regex will be next good solution for this problem. Thank You very much, now it is simple.
I will modify script with this tip, because it was important to not to lost data on prod server.